# Qt WidgetTable. Generating multiple data in just a push of a button

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

This is my first time using qt creator and a newbie to C++ language. I'm creating a GUI that will generate data (in numbers) into a widgetTable. My initial value of x serves as the starting point and the terminal value is my end point. the increment will be added to the initial value of x until it reaches the terminal value. 
How do I add the result VALUES into my widget table`enter

[image]

As you can see in my GUI there are two widget tables, the one on the left is composed of 2 columns.

Example:
Initial value of x is -5
Terminal value of x is 5
Increment is 1

Output on the column of values of x when Generate is clicked,
Values of x

```
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need help. I need to know what qt code is needed

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information abailable on the internet and official documentation with a lot of examples, you may take a look at this: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QTableWidget
and this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/model-view-programming.html

Basically, Qt uses model/view architecture, that means the data is placed somewhere NOT "in" widget. This "somewhere" is called a model (it has a lot of other functions by the way). It's mission is to hold the data. On the other hand is a view, that doesn't know anything about your data and asks the model to describe it. This approach gives a lot of advantages and is prefferable if you are planning to manipulate with data.

QTableWidget simplifies this approach hiding the model and giving you some functions like:

```
setItem(int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem * item)
item(int row, int column) const
```

and etc. (the whole list is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html)).

Well, this is how adding a simple text to the first row and a second column will look like:

```
_tableWidget->setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Hello"));
```

In your situation you'll need a `slot` with `for` cycle, that will generate such an objects, and connect it with your "Generate" button's `signal clicked()`.

```
connect(_generateButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(evalTable()));
```

Good luck.